# Using Python regex to scrape multiple words

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to parse out words by creating a python script and using regex.  How do I tag the words I'm trying to parse.  I'm very new to this and trying to learn, Is this even close?

```
import re

data = open('data.txt')

for line in data:
    if re.split((r'\s*', 'hack steal exploit compromise'), line):
        print line
```

Comment: Show some desirable output. And try to use re.split to notice the error in your code

Comment: Please include what data.txt looks like and the expected output of the script. Also, what do you mean by "_tag the words_"?

Comment: the data.txt file is a file with a bunch of random words, phrases, and numbers.  I am trying to parse out the following words: hack, steal, exploit, compromise.  By tag the words, I mean "How do I script it so only those words are shown in the output".  Sorry if using wrong verbiage.

Answer (score 2):

If you run your code, you'll see that you're passing the wrong argument to [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    if re.split((r'\s*', 'hack steal exploit compromise'), line):
  ...     
    raise TypeError("first argument must be string or compiled pattern")
TypeError: first argument must be string or compiled pattern
```

I don't know what you're trying to do with [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split).
But you can implement the parser instead using [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) or [`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match):

```
import re

data = open('data.txt')

for line in data:
    matches = re.search('(hack|steal|exploit|compromise)', line)
    if matches:
        print matches.group(1)  # get the 1st parenthesized group
```

The code above uses `re.search` (and `re.match`) that returns either a  [`MatchObject`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject) if the line contains any of the words "hack", "steal", "exploit", or "compromise", or `None` if the line doesn't contain any those words.

Then you can just get the [captured group](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group) which will be one of the 4 words that matched.

The script above will print something like:

```
hack        # data.txt: "blah blah blah hack"
compromise  # data.txt: "compromise blah blah"
exploit     # data.txt: "blah exploit blah"
```